# Buenas, necesito hacer un query que aumente un 10% el salario de algunos empleados? SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

como puedo hacerlo? Espero que me puedan ayudar, el comando debe ser para SQL SERVER 2017

Comment: Bienvenido, será necesario por favor leas [ask] pues no es solo indicar que requiere a sino además que has intentado

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tal vez algo como lo siguiente te serviría:

```
UPDATE EMPLEADOS SET SALARIO = SALARIO * 1.1 WHERE condicion
```

En donde ***condicion*** es el criterio que aplicaría para el incremento.

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo pero es necesario el OP muestre que lleva y no solo darle la respuesta, además que al no tener el contexto completo solo vamos a suponerv